# How to crop bottom of video followed by removing black borders?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have video where there is a static bar on the bottom 50 pixels and also a black boarder around the actual content.  I want to remove the bottom 50 pixels then use cropdetect to auto trim the border.

I have the following to remove the border

```
dims = $(ffmpeg -i "$video$ -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/{print $NF}' | tail -n1)

ffmpeg -i "$video" -vf "$dims" "$video_out"
```

I'm not sure how to add the step to remove the bottom 50 pixels prior to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another crop filter:

```
dims=$(ffmpeg -t 1 -i "$video" -vf crop=iw:ih-50:0:oh-ih,cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/{print $NF}' | tail -n1)

ffmpeg -i "$video" -vf "$dims" "$video_out"
```

Comment: option loop not found, stream_loop?

Comment: @pmdaly I was assuming an image input. I removed the option. Try without it.

Comment: Is it possible to apply a delay (-ss 2) for just the cropdetect and not the cropping?